# use array in yii tagcloud extension

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii-extensions, tag-cloud

i use yii tag cloud extension from the following link
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiitagcloud/

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.YiiTagCloud.YiiTagCloud', 
       array(
            'beginColor' => '00089A',
            'endColor' => 'A3AEFF',
            'minFontSize' => 8,
            'maxFontSize' => 20,
            'arrTags' => 
            array (
                    'MVC'     => array('weight'=> 2),
                    'PHP'     => array('weight'=> 9, 'url' => 'http://php.net'),
                    'MySQL'   => array('weight'=> 8, 'url' => 'http://mysql.com'),
                    'jQuery'  => array('weight'=> 6, 'url' => 'http://jquery.com'),
                    'SQL'     => array('weight'=> 9),
                    'C#'      => array('weight'=> 2),
            ),
      )
);
```

its working well for manual or static values but i want to use array here. the array structure is like this

```
Array ( 
    [toy] => 2 
    [not-possible ] => 1 
    [peace] => 1 
    [nedds] => 1 
    [fullfilment] => 1 
    [pakistan] => 1 
    [no-terrorism] => 1 
    [message-for-muslims] => 1 
    [a] => 1 
    [just ] => 1 
    [for-showoff] => 1 
    [a-dream] => 1 
    [peace-hen] => 1 
    [reality] => 1 
)
```

where key is the tag and value is its frequency. Now plz give me any idea to use this widget??

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the frequencies in `array('weight' => frequency)` in order to get an array similar to the manual/static one and pass this array into the widget. The widget will handle weighting appropriately.

Comment: are u @topher want to say the array is in the following form??      **Array ( [thrill] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [angry-mood] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [alligator] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [fears] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [persons] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [belongings] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) [missing] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) )**

Answer (score 0):

store the tags and weights in array in the following structure

```
    Array (
  [toy] => Array ( [weight] => 2 ) 
  [not-possible ] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [peace] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [nedds] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [fullfilment] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [pakistan] => Array ( [weight] => 1 )
  [no-terrorism] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [message-for-muslims] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [a] => Array ([weight] => 1 ) 
  [just ] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [for-showoff] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [a-dream] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [peace-hen] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
  [reality] => Array ( [weight] => 1 ) 
 )
```

and use this array in widget of line

```
 'arrtags'=>$tagsarray,
```

thanks @Topher for the idea.